# Java printff string only output formatting

Tags: java, printf, string-formatting, output-formatting

How do I format output by using printf.

suppose i want to print  following in formatter.

```
testing testing testing testing
testingggg  testingggg  testingggg  testingggg
```

I am not asking about using "\t", I am asking on printf style formatting? If some one can give me suggestion and example. Or may be link with example. I can do it to fit my need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class, which does printf-style formatting for Java.

For example, applied to your input:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);

    formatter.format("%1$-15s %2$-15s %3$-15s %4$-15s\n", "testing", "testing", "testing", "testing");
    formatter.format("%1$-15s %2$-15s %3$-15s %4$-15s", "testingggg", "testingggg", "testingggg", "testingggg");

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Produces:

```
testing         testing         testing         testing        
testingggg      testingggg      testingggg      testingggg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.out.printf("%sggg" , t)`

Where `t = "testing"`
and `ggg` is just appended onto this string.

Hope this helps :D

Comment: no that was just example..i want to print them as if they are in table?