# How to change my code for a proper output

Tags: java

Simple program to calculate seconds to hours, minutes and seconds.
However I am struggling with the output. How should I convert the code?

It's working but I am not satisfied with the output.

```
package whatever;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class whatever {
public static void main(String[] args){


int hours, minutes, seconds;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.printf("put seconds");
int secondz = in.nextInt();


int hour, minutes, seconds;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.printf("put seconds");
int secondz = in.nextInt();

hour = secondz / 60;
minutes = hour % 60;
seconds = minutes % 60;
hour = hour / 60;
  System.out.printf("it's  " +hours ,"hours" +minutes ,"minutes" +seconds ,"seconds");  // the output is "it's  36" only 


in.close();
}
}
```

Comment: "_I am not satisfied with the output._" Well, what does the output look like? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: the output is "it's " and gives just conversion to hours
I want it's ... hours ... minutes ... seconds

Comment: what is your input ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413020/how-to-use-formatting-with-printf-correctly-in-java

Comment: Whatever, in this case it was 456

Comment: hour hours minute minutes ?? check how you are using variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read how `printf` works. the first argument is the only one to the printed and the next are variables

```java
System.out.printf("it's %s hours, %s minutes, %s seconds", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Comment: Thank you! I wil :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line

```
System.out.printf("it's  " +hours ,"hours" +minutes ,"minutes" +seconds ,"seconds");
```

it used print-with-format, **printf**. Ether you have to use **println** or provide proper format, like:

```
System.out.printf("it's  %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds\n", hours , minutes, seconds);
```